# Admob account suspended due to "invalid activity on the AdSense ads hosted on your website"

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I am new to android and I have managed to read the admob guide lines and then adding the ads in my app and all was working just fine. Its been 3 month that I have uploaded my app and earned a little amount of money. But good so far for starter and beginners.

But today I have received the following message from the Google AdSense Account.

> We’d like you to know that we recently detected invalid activity on
>   the AdSense ads hosted on your website. We’ve temporarily suspended
>   your account and will re-enable it in 30 days. While your account is
>   suspended, you’ll still be able to log in to your AdSense account;
>   however, no ads will be served during this period. We hope this gives
>   you time to identify the source of the invalid activity and to take
>   appropriate action.

So I have 3 basic question

1. I do not understand what they have meant by **invalid activity on

   > the AdSense ads hosted on your website.** Although I do not have any website. I have just applied these ads in my apps
2. After 30 days they will active my account again , but I do not have clue What went wrong , so I am afraid after those 30 days, they would block me again and then forever. So How do I come to know that What I have done wrong ?
3. My 3rd Question is about what are the best guide  line would you people provide me to do with apps and ads I wanted to know I have seen many apps which even are not able to understand the standards of android but still they have 5000+ downloads, How they are doing all of this stuff. I do not understand how to promote app and how to earn with ads although I have read all the guideline but they are general I want you guys please give me honest technical advice.

I am looking forward if you participate in this discussion and make these points clear to me also to new Android developers. Thanks

Comment: One day morning I am waking up and seeing this in my email. I have not done any testing or debugging recently not within 10 days for sure and all my test devices show test ads only. Did that happen again after suspension period?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From googles support pages:

> Invalid click activity consists of any clicks or impressions that may artificially inflate an advertiser's costs or a publisher's earnings, and for which we decide not to charge the advertiser. This includes, but is not limited to, clicks or impressions generated by a publisher clicking his own ads, a publisher encouraging clicks on his ads, automated clicking tools or traffic sources, robots or other deceptive software.

Basically, they want genuine user interest. Most of the generated revenue from your app may have been from one person (intentional or not) which has lead them to believe that the clicks were fake. Google uses very sophisticated Artificial Intelligence program to track user mouse pointer location on the page and using the mouse pointer behavior it decides whether it’s a legit or fake click.  Sometimes the app or website owner will click the links themselves. This 30 day ban is a cooling off period.

Some common causes of bans regarding invalid clicks:

- Don't click your own ads (see above)
- Don't tell your friends to click on your ads
- A page impression can still be counted towards revenue. Don't let friends browse your ad hosting pages on your account (this will be viewed as YOU)
- Don't use copyrighted content
- Don’t post or host malicious content (hacking etc...)
- Don’t use pornographic materials on your site.
- Don’t use any other ad service on your website while using AdSense
- Don’t put more than 3 ads on any page.

Google recommends that to prevent invalid activity, that your ad implementation adheres to its policies.
[Here is a full list of Google AdSense policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182?vid=1-635774702430329188-3709557918) .

Google also has additional guidelines on how invalid activity can be prevented.
https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1112983

**Finally:**

Get involved with your Google Analytics to see where your users are coming from, and if you truly feel that you have been incorrectly banned, you can appeal here - [Invalid Activity Appeal](https://support.google.com/adsense/troubleshooter/2707037?hl=en).

Comment: but I do not have website and I my self didnt make any click on my app even I have not installed my app on my own testing device or personal device.

Comment: I said _app or website_ in response to you stating _adding the ads in my app_. I was making a generalization and giving an example of why google might suspend the ads on your account. You didn't have to click your own ads for this to happen but Google's Analytics detected that perhaps someone else did. Another reason may be the placement of the adds. If the number of clicks is high/close to the number of visits/impressions then it might bring up a red flag. The placement of the ads might have something to do with it, causing accidental clicking. The guidelines I posted have further information

Comment: good so far now I have one more thing to understand and I really do mess up and get confuse these terms as you said in this comment

Comment: what is ment by impressions and what is click ?

Comment: It's OK, it can be complicated. An **impression** is a page view, and a **click** is a someone clicking the ad. It isn't normal for these two numbers to be close to each other. Google may expect 25% of visitors to click an ad, but if that number is 75%, it might cause a red flag.

Comment: that is really well information you have provided me . So as I told you that I have not clicked my ads my self even I did not install my app in my cell , then How can now I minimize this risk ?

Comment: I have near 500 downloads only and I think near 50 installs , So now knowing these facts what would you suggest me to do ?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include a list of common causes. Just make sure that your app doesn't violate any of those points. I have also included a link to the appeal form!

Comment: why not , I am going to accept it as a answer and meanwhile you go and upvote my question as it would be going to help many of others who are facing same problem

Comment: do you know then How to promote the app ? if I am not going to tell my friends on facebook post that I have made this app (as you said above dont post it on facebook) so what is other way to tell others about my app

Comment: I think their policy on this is more to do with asking your friends to click your adverts. This is similar to the second point on the list (I might remove it). You can advertise the app itself no problem

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89260/discussion-between-coas-mckey-and-smittey).

Answer (score 4):

Forget Admob and use [Facebook audience network](https://developers.facebook.com/products/audience-network/overview/) ads.
its great ads network for mobile ads And you will get 30% more revenue than Adsense.

Comment: yes your true i am using fb , admob required like pubg apps not our simple apps my calculator app they detect invalid activity mine is pure app no invalid activity